# (iOS & Xcode)How can I do somthing before I tap the Button of a segmentControl?

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol

I want to do something when I touch the button of a segmentControl and it doesn't have changed its selectedIndex,what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

if the button in question is a UIButton you might be able to accomplish this by registering 2 different selectors to the UIButton inherited from UIControl.

```
[_theButton addTarget:self action:@selector(mySelectorBeforeAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[_theButton addTarget:self action:@selector(mySelectorAfterAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

UIControlEventTouchCancel : A system event canceling the current touches for the control.

UIControlEventTouchDown : A touch-down event in the control.

UIControlEventTouchDownRepeat  : A repeated touch-down event in the control; for this event the value of the UITouch tapCount method is greater than one.

UIControlEventTouchDragEnter  : An event where a finger is dragged into the bounds of the control.

UIControlEventTouchDragExit  : An event where a finger is dragged from within a control to outside its bounds.

UIControlEventTouchDragInside : An event where a finger is dragged inside the bounds of the control.

UIControlEventTouchDragOutside  : An event where a finger is dragged just outside the bounds of the control.

UIControlEventTouchUpInside : A touch-up event in the control where the finger is inside the bounds of the control.

UIControlEventTouchUpOutside  : A touch-up event in the control where the finger is outside the bounds of the control.